# Преобразование byte[] в строку и обратно

Tags: android, java

Что я делаю не так?

```
Bitmap bmp = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
Arrays.equals(bytes, new String(bytes).getBytes()); // false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень, конечно, понимаю потайной смысл этого выражения

```
Arrays.equals(bytes, new String(bytes).getBytes()); // false
```

Но прокомментирую:

Во-первых, вы, наверное, не в курсе, что не каждый набор байтов можно транслировать в строку. Так что `new String(bytes)` может вернуть все что угодно, например, обрезать нетранслированные байты. Как говорит мануал:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified.

Во-вторых, здесь упущен один очень важный параметр - кодировка, по умолчанию применяется текущая кодировка платформы, что делает код нетранспортабельным. В разных платформах/устройствах результат будет разный.

Comment: указание UTF-8 в качестве кодировки дает тот же ответ. Тоже думаю, что в итоге были потеряны какие-то символы.

Comment: @Juggler ну так System.out.println(Arrays.toString(...)) сделай. учись дебажить самостоятельно.

Comment: @Juggler вы так ничего и не поняли: с чего вы взяли, что набор байтов после JPEG компрессии можно транслировать в виде UTF-8 строки? Кодировка UTF-8 представляет собой не бессмысленный набор байтов, а предполагает строго упорядоченную последовательность с соответствующим заголовком и проч. причиндалами. Это примерно то же самое, что ожидать, что в наборе байтов случайно окажется строка *Hello World!*

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что вы делаете не так.

```
byte[] bytes = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
boolean equals = Arrays.equals(bytes, new String(bytes).getBytes());
Log.e("EQUALS", String.valueOf(equals));//true
```